# pd.eval - transforming fraction to float and skip errors (drop errors)

Tags: python, pandas, eval, transformation

Trying my first data project and want to run k-means on some trade data and need your help. I got a column that contains the coupon of the bond, but uses different formats on different lines in the "Coupon column". Line 1 says "7.2" while line 2 says "8 1/4". I need to transform this to floats. After googeling a lot I found pd.eval.

```
df.Coupon = df.Coupon.fillna(0).apply(pd.eval)
```

**Error:**
`pd.eval` seems to work on most of the lines, but spits out this error here:

```
  *File "C:\Users\Schnexit\anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 47, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    8 1 /4
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax*
```

**Question:**
I assume, that this is due to the space between "1" and "/". Is this assumtion correct? Any way to fix this automatically, without going manually through 60k lines of data? ;)
Alternatively, I would like to simply ignore the error and delete the false line from the dataframe.

Comment: use `df.Coupon=df.Coupon.str.replace(' ','',regex=True)` after that use `df.Coupon.fillna(0).apply(pd.eval)`

Comment: Well actually...this causes a few other issues:
1. it transforms 8 1/4 (=8.25) to 81/4 (=20.25)
2. when there are multiple " ", the error remains: 8" "1" "/4 it transforms to 81" "/4

Comment: try:  `df.Coupon=df.Coupon.replace(' ','',regex=True)`

Comment: please show Coupon Column sample data, as you are facing many issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a fraction valid for `pd.eval()` to work. *"2 1/2"* needs to be *"2+1/2"*

Generated some sample date to demonstrate.  Including space padding around forward slash.

```
import random
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"coupon":[f"{random.randint(1,3)} {random.randint(1,4)}{' '[:random.randint(0,1)]}/{' '[:random.randint(0,1)]}{random.randint(1,10)}" for i in range(5)]
                  +[f"{round(random.uniform(1,4),2)}" for i in range(5)] + [np.nan]})

df.assign(couponn=df.coupon.fillna("0").str.replace("[ ]?(/)[ ]?", r"\1", regex=True).str.replace(" ","+").apply(pd.eval))
```

|  | coupon | couponn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 3 /10 | 2.3 |
| 1 | 2 4/3 | 3.33333 |
| 2 | 3 3 /7 | 3.42857 |
| 3 | 3 4 / 10 | 3.4 |
| 4 | 3 4 /1 | 7 |
| 5 | 3.94 | 3.94 |
| 6 | 2.51 | 2.51 |
| 7 | 1.1 | 1.1 |
| 8 | 2.3 | 2.3 |
| 9 | 2.87 | 2.87 |
| 10 | nan | 0 |

Comment: Thanks. that makes sense. But i still have the problem that there sometimes is a space bevor the "/" ... so in some fields I see "8_1_/4"... I guess I would need to replace the first "_" with "+" and the second one with "". ... Do you know how to do this?

Comment: ok - updated - use a regex replace to remove padded spaces and then a simple replace for eval to work

Comment: This results in "UndefinedVariableError: name 'nan' is not defined"

Comment: Have updated again - you really should provide a sample data set of what is in your complete data. standard practice to build a test dataset for unit / integration testing that you use for test driven development and continuous integration